# Query CPU ID from Python?

Tags: python, windows, cpu

How I can find processor id with py2.6, windows OS?

I know that there is pycpuid, but I can't compile this under 2.6.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [wmi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/)? (It may require elevated privilege level)

[Here's a solution](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t359596-cpu-or-mb-serial-number.html) (it works for Python 2 and 3):

```
>>> import wmi
>>> c = wmi.WMI()
>>> for s in c.Win32_Processor():
    print (s)



instance of Win32_Processor
{
    AddressWidth = 64;
    Architecture = 9;
    Availability = 3;
    Caption = "Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5";
    CpuStatus = 1;
    CreationClassName = "Win32_Processor";
    CurrentClockSpeed = 3068;
    DataWidth = 64;
    Description = "Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5";
    DeviceID = "CPU0";
    ExtClock = 133;
    Family = 1;
    L2CacheSize = 1024;
    L3CacheSize = 8192;
    L3CacheSpeed = 0;
    Level = 6;
    LoadPercentage = 3;
    Manufacturer = "GenuineIntel";
    MaxClockSpeed = 3068;
    Name = "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz";
    NumberOfCores = 4;
    NumberOfLogicalProcessors = 8;
    PowerManagementSupported = FALSE;
    ProcessorId = "BFEBFBFF000106A5";
    ProcessorType = 3;
    Revision = 6661;
    Role = "CPU";
    SocketDesignation = "CPU 1";
    Status = "OK";
    StatusInfo = 3;
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    SystemName = "RYAN-PC";
    UpgradeMethod = 1;
    Version = "";
    VoltageCaps = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) command is always available on Windows-XP, and use `subprocess.Popen` to run it, rather than require my users to install any special Python packages.

```
C:\>wmic cpu get ProcessorId /format:csv

Node,ProcessorId
E100325,BFEBFBFF00000F43
E100325,BFEBFBFF00000F43
```

Comment: Great, no need to install other third-party packages. Win-8.1 also works.

Comment: unless that command is reporting an error due to access rights restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two projects with that name.  Did you try both?

- [Bram de Greve](http://www.bramz.net/projects-code/pycpuid/)
- [arun.sharma](http://code.google.com/p/pycpuid/)

Comment: Both were unable to work on py 2.6. All examples cpuid by arun.sharma return 0.