# How to get CPU serial number on Windows using Python?

Tags: python, windows, cpu

I wrote a program in Python-3.6.2 on Windows 10. I want get the CPU serial number.

Here is my code:

```
def getserial():
    # Extract serial from cpuinfo file
    cpuserial = "0000000000000000"
    try:
        f = open('/proc/cpuinfo','r')
        for line in f:
            if line[0:6]=='Serial':
                cpuserial = line[10:26]
        f.close()
    except:
        cpuserial = "ERROR000000000"
  return cpuserial

print(getserial())
```

When I run the program, it prints: `ERROR000000000`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @jedwards,i use windows 10.

Comment: @naghi. Do you need this to **only** work on windows, and not linux, osx, etc? If so, you should make this clear in your question.

Comment: @ekhumoro ,yes i want it only for windows

Comment: @naghi. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3056836/984421).

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't let any exception raised. So, you don't see the error: There is no '/proc/cpuinfo' file on Windows.

I have rewrite your code  like that:

```
def getserial():
    # Extract serial from cpuinfo file
    with open('/proc/cpuinfo','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line[0:6] == 'Serial':
                return line[10:26]
        return "0000000000000000"
```

First, I have a `with` statement to use the file context manager: whenever an exception is raised or not, your file will be closed.

And I simplify the loop: if it found a "Serial" entry, it returns the value.

**EDIT**

If you have python with a version >= 2.6 you can simply use

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count

**EDIT2**

The best solution I found to get the "cpuinfo" is with the [py-cpuinfo](https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo) library.

```
import cpuinfo
info = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()
print(info)
```

But, I think that "Serial" entry is not standard. I can't see it on classic systems.

Comment: ,how get  cpuserial  in windows?

Comment: @naghi: The title is ”How get cpu cpuserial in python?” (not Windows). But I understand its frustration. There are several flaws in its question.

Comment: i want use it Unique identifier as user in windows in program,what is your offer?

Comment: @naghi: You _could_ have it's serial number with `cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()`.

Comment: Even if my links point to the Python 3.6.2 version, I'm pretty sure they are backward compatible… So give it a try!